# syntax error insert while expression to complete blockstatements JAVA

Tags: java

this is my code so far to make a program which accepts numbers between 1 and 100 inputted by the user and only even numbers. it also needs to end when N or n is inputted and calculates the sum of valid numbers aswell as displaying the highest number.

i have an error which says Syntax error insert "while (expression)"; to complete block statements on this pice of code...:

'System.out.println("Enter the list of whole numbers, pressing N or n will Calculate your numbers");'

any help would be greatly appreciated.

- This is the start of the code: -

```j
package week11;
import java.util.*;
public class repeatlist {

public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 0, Sum = 0; //variables
        char letter;
        char choice;

        //if (Number %2 ==0)
        {
        do

            System.out.println("Enter the list of whole numbers, pressing N or n will Calculate your numbers");
            number = sc.nextInt();
            letter = sc.next().charAt(0);


            {
                 while(letter != 'N' && letter != 'n' ); 
                    System.out.println("end of program");

                Sum = Sum + number;
                number = sc.nextInt(); 

            System.out.println("Sum is "+ Sum);
            System.out.print("Do you want to repeat the ");
            System.out.println("  Program ['Y' or 'N']");
            choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Forget about the code for a second. Do you know how to write a `do-while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the list of whole numbers, pressing N or n will Calculate your numbers");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        letter = sc.next().charAt(0);
    } 
    while (letter != 'N' && letter != 'n' ); 
    System.out.println("end of program");

    Sum = Sum + number;
    number = sc.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("Sum is "+ Sum);
    System.out.print("Do you want to repeat the ");
    System.out.println("  Program ['Y' or 'N']");
    choice = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

Try to keep your code well formatted, all IDEs have an option to format it for you. It will help you spot these kind of

Comment: i kept getting errors on the brackets and if i added more like it is now those went away. im pretty new to this so still learning by the way

Comment: also this code change took the error away. im one step closer to getting the whole thing to work so thankyou.

Comment: ahh okay, i was also wondering if you can see were im going wrong with the end of the program. i have the code that calculates the sum, but i dont know what order i need the code in for it to do it and print it. ive tried moving it around but it dosent seem to work

Comment: Difficult to help without writing it for you, which I think is not the point. Here are some hints: keep in mind that in order to have the `Do you want to repeat the program` functionality, your whole main logic would have to be inside of do-while loop. Also, you should check the user input (just because you expect the user to input a number, doesn't mean he won't enter a letter, leading to exception).

Answer (score 1):

A good example of why indentation is important. Your current loop esentially does the following:

```
{
    do System.out.println("Enter the list of whole numbers, pressing N or n will Calculate your numbers");

    //Rest of your first code block 

    {
        while (letter != 'N' && letter != 'n'); //Does nothing

        //Your second code block
    }
}
```

A lot of unnecessary brackets and statements that will lead to your code not running as expected.

Maybe you are looking for

```
do {
    //Your first code block
    //Your second code block
} while (letter != 'N' && letter != 'n' );
```

or

```
do {
    //Your first code block
} while (letter != 'N' && letter != 'n' );
//Your second code block
```